# What do I need to do to read the date in a column?

Tags: sql, ms-access

In acess I have to place old timer by all the people that was hire before 2000? I have the code written and when I run the code it puts old timer by all the people. I don't want it to do that I want it only by people hired by 2000. I cannot figure out what I'm doing work because I wrote code to do this for a price for an item to was EXPENSIVE and it worked fine. But doing this by date hired I seem to be lost. Here is the select statement that I wrote maybe someone can lead me on the right path?

```
select employee_id,
   hire_date,
   'OLD TIMER' as message
from l_employees
where hire_date > 2000
union all
select employee_id,
   hire_date,
   ' '
from l_employees
where not (hire_date >2000)
or hire_date is null
order by  employee_id;
```

When I change the select statement I get the result I want by the dollar amount I need it but i need this to happen when I use the hire date is a date/time datatype.

```
select employee_id,
credit_limit,
'OLD TIMER' as message
from l_employees
where credit_limit > 15.00
union all
select employee_id,
credit_limit,
' '
from l_employees
where not credit_limit > 15.00
or credit_limit is null
order by  employee_id;
```

here is the result I get form that statement

```
 employee_id    credit_limit    message
         201      $30.00    OLD TIMER
         202      $25.00    OLD TIMER
         203      $25.00    OLD TIMER
         204      $15.00     
         205      $25.00    OLD TIMER
         206         
         207      $25.00    OLD TIMER
         208      $25.00    OLD TIMER
         209      $15.00     
         210      $25.00    OLD TIMER
         211      $40.00    OLD TIMER
```

This is the output for the very top select statement

```
 employee_id    hire_date   message
         201    6/1/1998    OLD TIMER
         202    8/16/1999   OLD TIMER
         203    2/2/2009    OLD TIMER
         204    7/1/2008    OLD TIMER
         205    3/1/2006    OLD TIMER
         206         
         207    12/1/2008   OLD TIMER
         208    4/1/2008    OLD TIMER
         209    3/17/1999   OLD TIMER
         210    2/16/2007   OLD TIMER
         211    2/3/2014    OLD TIMER
```

Just to update I found out how to get the result that I was looking for thanks for all the help I got with this problem.

Comment: What is the data type of hire_date? In fact, add the schema for your table to the question. Also your code seems to be written for placing `'OLD TIMER'` for employees hired **after** 2000.

Comment: try using `YEAR(hire_date)>2000` !

Comment: Not sure I like the phrase 'old-timer' used in a serious application. It sounds derogatory, ageist.

Comment: Yawar that is the way it is in the book and I'm only doing what I'm told to do. Sorry this offends you.

Answer (score 2):

```
select employee_id,
       hire_date,
       switch(
              year(hire_date) < 2000, 'OLD TIMER'
              , true, 'Greenhorn'
             )as message
from l_employees
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select employee_id,
   hire_date,
   'OLD TIMER' as message
from l_employees
where hire_date < 20000101
union all
select employee_id,
   hire_date,
   ' '
from l_employees
where hire_date >= 20000101
or hire_date is null
order by  employee_id;
```

This is working for me on a test table.
Here I am specifying dates in the form of YYYYMMDD and not just YYYY.

Comment: I have just try it your way and for some reason old timer is still being place by all the employess.

Comment: Then please post your table schema and some sample data to help find the problem.

Comment: l_employees(employee_id, first_name, last_name, dept_code, hire_date, credit_limit, Phone_number, manager_id)

Comment: When I change the select statment to credit_limit i get what I'm looking for as placing old timer by the right dollar amount. AS I post the result

Comment: sorry for the *AS was not yelling just had cap lock on

Comment: That's okay. Could you also add the output of `desc l_employees;` to the question? Also have you tried what the comment on your question suggested, that is using `YEAR(hire_date) > 2000`?